# How can I do this double integral?

Tags: calculus

Im trying to calculate this integral:

$$\int_0^1 \int_e^{e^y} \frac{1}{\ln(x)} dx ~dy$$

Wolfram calculates that it is equal to $1-e$. I have no idea how to do this problem.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{\ln x} = x \cdot\frac {1/x}{\ln x}$.

Comment: Changing the order kills $\ln x$.

Comment: @Tianlalu How does it change?
$$\int_e^{e^y}  \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{\ln(x)} dy ~dx = \int_e^{e^y} \frac{1}{ln(x)} dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that
$$\int_{y=0}^1 \left(\int_{x=e}^{e^y} \frac{1}{\ln(x)} dx\right)dy=\int_{x=e}^1 \frac{1}{\ln(x)}\left(\int_{y=?}^{?}  dy\right)dx.$$

Comment: That's exactly my doubt, I don't know the limits of this new integral.

Comment: Make a drawing of the domain of integration and  consider the bounding curves such as $x=e^y$.